std::optional на константную ссылку
Можно ли в std::optional использовать константную ссылку на объект (const T&), чтобы избежать копирования? По поводу ссылки в optional видел много чего, а насчет константной ссылки ничего.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Так вроде ссылки в optional не компилируются.

@HolyBlackCat, вы правы, ссылки любые запрещены в std::optional.
